# Recurring payments being set to pending - Stripe

Tags: civimember, recurring-contributions, stripe

I've inherited a CiviCRM 5.21.0 install on Wordpress, using Stripe to process membership payments. When a member chooses the "recurring payment" option on signup (Please renew my membership automatically), CiviCRM doesn't accept that as paid and doesn't add them as members. Instead they are listed as

Pending (Incomplete Transaction)

Non-recurring memberships are entered without a problem.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any stripe warnings on your System Status page?
What version of Stripe extension do you have?
Do you have any notices about Stripe webhooks?

Comment: Aha that nailed it, thanks! There were notices and fixing them resolved the issue.

Comment: Great - i rewrote it to an Answer to help others. Pls Accept and +1 it. cheers

Answer (score 2):

Go to your System Status page and check for any stripe warnings

In particular look for any notices about Stripe webhooks that might need resetting.

Also ensure you are on latest versions.